# How to load the local html page using intent in Android?

Tags: android

I have a html file in my asset directory and i have to load it as browser application using Intent.

Here is my code, but its not working:

```
startActivity (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
               Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/Sample.htm")));
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You can simply show using webview also .

Answer (score 0):

Use `loadUrl()` method of `WebView` to load an html page

**Sample Example**
if faq.html is the html file present in assets folder then you can use

```
WebView html = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webEulaView);
html.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/faq.html");
```

Comment: that would be loading it into a WebView.  The question is how to launch the browser from the app.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem what i did was 
copied the content of the assets to a database and then pulled it from the sdcard

here is the code to copy your assets to sdcard 
the logic used is as follows  the html pages are put in the zip file in assets folder 
content is the name of the zip in assets folder

```
    boolean succussFlag = false; 
    destination="";
    destination=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/";
    File file = new File(destination);

    if (!file.exists()){
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    else
    {
        //file.delete();
        //file.mkdir();
    }
    try
    {
        InputStream fileInput = context.getAssets().open("content.zip");
        ZipInputStream inputStream = new ZipInputStream(fileInput);

        for (ZipEntry entry = inputStream.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry = inputStream.getNextEntry())
        {
            String innerFileName = destination +  entry.getName();
            System.out.println("destination::::"+innerFileName);
            //              Log.v("inner file name 0",""+innerFileName);
            File innerFile = new File(innerFileName);
            if (innerFile.exists())
            {

                innerFile.delete();
            }

            // Check if it is a folder
            if (entry.isDirectory())
            {
                // Its a folder, create that folder
                innerFile.mkdirs();
            }
            else
            {
                //                  System.out.println(" ::::::::::::::INNER FILE COPYING :::: " + innerFile.toString());
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(innerFileName);
                final int BUFFER = 4096;

                BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream,
                        BUFFER);

                int count = 0;
                byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER];
                while ((count = inputStream.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1)
                {
                    bufferedOutputStream.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                bufferedOutputStream.flush();
                bufferedOutputStream.close();
            }

            inputStream.closeEntry();
        }
        inputStream.close();
        //          System.out.println(" ::::::::::COPIED TO PRIVATE FOLDER ::::  " );
        succussFlag=true;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        //          System.out.println("** EXCEPTION OCCURED WHILE COPYING***");
        e.printStackTrace();
        succussFlag=false;
    }

    return succussFlag;
```

after this you give following command

```
startActivity (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,"file://"+     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/content"+name_Html ;
         );
```

Comment: there has to be an easier way than copying files from assets to sd card. that makes no sense.