# Localhost in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk

I want to load the index.html file in webview from **http://127.0.0.1/html/andhel/index.html**

Now where I want to create the **html** and **andhel** directories in android tablet?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Android isn't going to be serving up HTML, a web server is. Also, to access localhost from the Android emulator, you need to use 10.0.2.2.

Comment: OK. If a button is clicked, I want to load an html file which is present inside android tablet. (say Downloads folder). Now how can I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676734/how-to-load-the-local-html-page-using-intent-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 127.0.0.1/html/andhel/index.html

use **http://10.0.2.2/html/andhel/index.html**

thats it!! but test it from the Emulator ... testing that from a device needs more things to be done.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **10.0.2.2** instead of **127.0.0.1**, because

> 10.0.2.2 is the special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your
>   development machine)

For more information about [emulator networking](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking)

The main reason is, the emulator will not look at you host file located in your local machine, and will not make use of it.

There are some workarounds to use your own virtual hosts, take a look on following links

http://www.bradcurtis.com/2011/02/13/hosts-file-google-android-emulator/

http://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/soup-to-nuts-getting-your-android-emulator-to-read-virtual-hosts-on-your-development-machine/

Answer (score 0):

if your index.html is in your computer that your AVD is installed in use 10.0.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Android Emulator is not installed like a normal application on your machine. It is a virtual machine instance with a unique IP address and physical address. Therefore , anything that is being served on your machine does can not be access as localhost on the emulator. You should access it with complete ip address as if it were on some other machine on the network, instead of localhost.